# Phoenix + Channels: How to ensure that both parties have "accepted"?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Part of Apple's requirements for video chatting is that both parties must explicitly press "accept" before they can enter a video chat.

I have an "accept" button that calls this function when pressed:

My view:

```
  channel.on("match_accepted", payload => {
    if (payload.matched_client_email == matchedClientEmail) {
      this.setState({ clientQueued: true });
    }
  });

  acceptMatch() {
    ...
    if (this.state.clientQueued) {
      // start video session
    } else {
      // notify the other person that you have accepted
      channel.push("accept_match", {
        "matched_client_email": matchedClientEmail,
      });
    }
  }
```

Call channel:

```
  def handle_in("accept_match", %{ "matched_client_email" => matched_client_email }, socket) do
    # broadcast to the other person that you have accepted
    VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
      "user_pool:#{matched_client_email}",
      "match_accepted",
      %{ matched_client_email: socket.assigns[:email] }
    )

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

This is very brittle since I have no way of guaranteeing that the `state` (it's a react thing) will have been updated by the time the person presses the button. Therefore, they could potentially both accept at the same time and just hang in limbo.

Is there a better way to ensure that both people have pressed accept? I was thinking about doing it through Phoenix's `Presence` library and storing a property in the `metas` key, but with the current way I have it, all clients are in their own channels / rooms, so each Presence list would only have one record (...right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, it seems like the chat server should be the one that determines both users have accepted. So:

```
user1 presses accept -> sends "accept_match" to chat server
user2 presses accept -> sends "accept_match" to chat server

chat server sees both has accepted
    -> broadcasts "start_session"
```

Here's a quick example using an `Agent` per session and broadcasting to both if they have accepted. There is *most definitely* an easier/more efficient way to do this.

View:

```
channel.on("session_started", payload => {
    if (payload.matched_client_email == matchedClientEmail) {
        this.setState({ sessionStarted: true });
        // start video session
    }
});

acceptMatch() {
    channel.push("accept_match", {
        "matched_client_email": matchedClientEmail,
    });
}
```

Channel call:

```
def handle_in("accept_match", %{ "matched_client_email" => matched_client_email }, socket) do
  Agent.update agent_session_pid, fn state ->
     Map.put(state, socket.assigns[:email], true)
  end
  # check to see if we should broadcast acceptance
  matched_accepted = Agent.get(agent_session_pid, &(Map.get(&1, matched_client_email)))
  case matched_accepted do
     true ->
       # broadcast to each user
       VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
         "user_pool:#{matched_client_email}",
         "session_started",
         %{ matched_client_email: socket.assigns[:email] }
       )

       VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
         "user_pool:#{socket.assigns[:email]}",
         "session_started",
         %{ matched_client_email:  }
       )

       {:noreply, socket}
    _ ->
      {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Thanks so much! What exactly is Agent? And where is `agent_session_pid` coming from?